# Google sheets - generate numbers from 1 to N where N is a parameter

Tags: google-sheets

I want to generate numbers from 1 to N, where N is the parameter that I can control. And I want to generate no more no less N numbers in N rows.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Excel or google sheet or both?

Comment: Google sheet only is enough @CodeCamper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a direct

```
=sequence(14)
```

or with a cell reference

```
=sequence(J2)
```